# Phonegap - I have the basic hello world android app. How do I deploy it to ios?

Tags: ios, cordova

I've installed phonegap, and got the basic hello world new project app open in eclipse. I have deployed it to a android emulator. I want to deploy the same app to my IOS emulator. I can't find any instructions anywhere of how to do this. Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this in Xcode on Mac, or in a virtual machine with Mac OS installed.
Also, cordova.js is different for Android and iOS platforms - keep this in mind, as the codebase will differ in some ways for these platforms.

Here is the complete guide about building Phonegap apps for iOS:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_ios_index.md.html#iOS%20Platform%20Guide

Answer (score 0):

If you have iOS Dev license you can build it through **PhoneGap Build.**

The advantage is that you don't have to have a Mac or even a virtual machine with Mac installed, so that you can do everything through a web interface, what's fantastic!

The only exception is if you have something native in Xcode to deploy along with your application, otherwise if it's only HTML/Javascript and so on, then it's perfect for you.

**http://build.phonegap.com**

Hope it helps!